# Any way to reference an attribute of a parameter in the query?

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa, hql, jpql

Is there any way to reference an attribute of a parameter that is part of a query for a JPA repository?

My sample is

```
@Entity
public class Matchday implements Serializable {
    @Id
    private int matchdayNumber;
    //..
    //setters and getters defined
    //..
    //hashCode and equals methods overridden
}

public interface MyRepository extends JpaRepository<Matchday, Integer> {
    @Query("... WHERE t.matchday.matchdayNumber < :matchday.matchdayNumber - 1;")
    public findByCriteria(Matchday matchday);
}
```

The construction `:matchday.matchdayNumber` does not seem to be a valid syntax. Is there any other way to do it than passing the `int` value for `matchdayNumber` instead of a reference to `Matchday` object to this method?

Comment: works in the JPA provider that I use (DataNucleus).

Comment: Hmmmm, does not seem to work with Hibernate.

Comment: so pass in the parameter as the ":matchdayNumber"

Comment: Yep, this is my workaround, which I stated in the question anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like this is possible with [Spring JPA Data](https://spring.io/blog/2014/07/15/spel-support-in-spring-data-jpa-query-definitions) which allows SpEL in queries.

```
public interface MyRepository extends JpaRepository<Matchday, Integer> {
    @Query("... WHERE t.matchday.matchdayNumber < :#{#matchday.matchdayNumber - 1}")
    public findByCriteria(Matchday matchday);
}
```